# Achievement doesn't collapse when opening your profile using the widget

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

The achievement box doesn't close when opening your profile using the widget, this clearly looks like a bug:

[image]

This bug can be reproduced 100 % out of the time.

Using application version 1.0.82.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open StackExchange and click archievements
2. Go to your home page using the home button on your phone
3. Use the widget to open StackExchange again
4. Observe the bug

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]